# Don't validate deletion in Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I want to prevent users from adding a row with a name that is already in the table, so part of my validation checks that that's the case. But this means that if the user tries to delete a row, they will not be able to save the deletion, since the validation fails. How can I have validation that runs only when the user is creating a row, but skipped when for when the user is deleting a row?

```js
validate: rowData => rowData.name != null && !rowsState.some(x => String(x.name) === String(rowData.name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate between a row that has already been added to the table, compared to a row that is being created, via whether it has a `tableData` property. If the `tableData` property is undefined, then the row is still being created; otherwise, the row is being edited or deleted.

We can change the code to this:

```js
validate: rowData => rowData.tableData !== undefined || (rowData.requirementId != null && !rowsState.some(x => String(x.requirementId) === String(rowData.requirementId)))
```

For this table, I only have `onRowAdd` and `onRowDelete` in the `editable` prop of `<MaterialTable>`, with no `onRowUpdate`. In the case that we want to allow editing a row, it would be more difficult to let the callback of `validate` differentiate between editing and deleting a row, as in either scenario the row would have a `tableData` property.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question at the same time? Did you create it just to get some rep? And there is a PR to fix this actually, so it should not be a problem soon. https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/pull/2634

Comment: @Domino987 This is a real question that I had and about fifteen minutes after I started writing the question, I thought of an answer. Thanks for letting me know about the pull request! Regarding self-answering, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer